# Fatal Error index out of range swift 3 SpriteKit

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit, fatal-error

I am trying to make a two player shooter game. I am trying to destroy bullets that you have already used. In the update I am using the code

```
 var bulletsChecked = 0


    for b in bullets {

        if b.pos.y > self.frame.height || b.pos.y < -self.frame.height {

            bullets.remove(at: bulletsChecked)

            print("destroy old bullets")



        }
```

I also have bulletsChecked += 1 at the end of the update. This code works fine unless Player one and Player two shoot at the same time. Then I get the "Fatal Error index out of range" error on the "bullets.remove(at: bulletsChecked)" Any thoughts?

Comment: When you delete a bullet, you throw off the indices of the remaining bullets. Two ways to fix 1) Only increment bulletsChecked when you haven't deleted a bullet. or 2) iterate backwards through your array `for (index,b) in bullets.enumerated().reversed() { if bullet meets criteria { bullets.remove(at: index) }}`

Comment: If you want to remove bullets that are out of the screen, you can proceed in two better way: 1) add physics loop of the screen and remove the bullet that contact with it. 2) When you shoot the bullet (I think is applyImpulse) add a sequence of SKAction that remove the bullet after some time delay. If you want mantain your code, use var bullets = Set<Bullet>()    and now you can use b.remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the index issue by going though your array in reverse order.

```
for b in bullets.reversed() {
...
}
```

[EDIT] you could also use a filter to remove bullets from the array.

For example:

```
bullets = bullets.filter 
{
   bullet in 
   return bullet.pos.y >  self.frame.height 
       || bullet.pos.y < -self.frame.height
}
```

Note that i'm not clear on how your test for bullet deletion produces the required result, but I assume that it does what you want it to do and that it does not try deleting bullets that aren't supposed to be deleted.

Comment: Thank you this works for bot bullets going out of frame but if they both hit each other I get the same error. here is my code...down bellow

Answer (score 0):

//====== COLLISION BETWEEN BULLETT AND PLAYER 2

```
        if canHitP2 {

        if b.pos.y >= self.frame.height - P2.size.height && (b.pos.x >= P2.position.x - P2.size.width / 2 && b.pos.x <= P2.position.x + P2.size.width / 2){

            print("Player 2 hit")

            bullets.remove(at: bulletsChecked)

            P1Scored()

            P2.removeFromParent()

            P2CanShoot = false

            canHitP2 = false

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: Delay) {

                self.P2Spawn()

                self.addChild(self.P2)

                P2CanShoot = true

                canHitP2 = true

            }


        }

        }


        //====== COLLISION BETWEEN BULLETT AND PLAYER 1

        if canHitP1 {

        if b.pos.y <= -self.frame.height + P1.size.height && (b.pos.x >= P1.position.x - P1.size.width / 2 && b.pos.x <= P1.position.x + P1.size.width / 2) {

            print("Player 1 hit")

            bullets.remove(at: bulletsChecked)

            P2Scored()

            P1.removeFromParent()

            P1CanShoot = false

            canHitP1 = false

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: Delay) {

                self.P1Spawn()

                self.addChild(self.P1)

                P1CanShoot = true

                canHitP1 = true



            }


        }

        }
```